# Large number of pages redirect via .htaccess and database query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I take in an input to a domain (requested URL) and put it through my own php file (which will do the db query and then redirect users to proper location?

We basically have 1500+ pages that we are going to redirect. And URL structure is not exactly identical enough to be able to just do a simple .htaccess redirect.

If we can get it to read it in a .php file, I think I can make a script inside of that easily.

Comment: Can you provide some examples and a little more detail. How different are the urls? Could you create a few different rules to capture them all?

Comment: This is very possible using PHP.  What have you tried?

Comment: Can you post example urls?

Answer (score 1):

You must capture the URL path, redirect to your PHP script and add the path as a query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* /script.php?$0 [QSA]
```

This will redirect all requests to `script.php` with the URL path as the first `$_GET` argument. The original query string, if any, will be appended (`[QSA]`) to this as the second and following `$_GET` arguments.

Comment: I will try this out and then post a complete solution on how I did it. Thank you!